# C# MySql error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets, firewall

I have a strange problem when working with MySql in C#. When executing the command sometimes(not always) I get "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" error. I cannot solve this problem and can't find any solution in web.

As a workaround I developed simple ReConnection class. When this exception occurs I simply call ReOpen() method. It works perfectly with ADO.NET and I am using this trick more than 2 year.

```
public class ReConnection : DbConnection
{
    private readonly int _reconnectAttempts;
    private readonly int _reconnectInterval;

    private bool _isOpened;
    private int _reConnectSessions;
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    private readonly DbCommand _pingCommand;
    private readonly DbConnection _innerConnection;

    public ReConnection(DbConnection innerConnection,
        int reconnectAttempts = 4, int reconnectInterval = 1000)
    {
        _innerConnection = innerConnection;

        _pingCommand = _innerConnection.CreateCommand();
        _pingCommand.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";

        _reconnectAttempts = reconnectAttempts;
        _reconnectInterval = reconnectInterval;
    }

    public override void Open()
    {
        _innerConnection.Open();
        _isOpened = true;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _isOpened = false;
        while (_reConnectSessions > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        _innerConnection.Close();
    }

    internal bool ReOpen()
    {
        var restored = false;
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            _reConnectSessions++;
            var retries = _reconnectAttempts;
            try
            {
                _pingCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                restored = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                while (_isOpened &&
                       ((retries > 0) || (_reconnectAttempts == -1)) &&
                       !restored)
                {
                    if ((retries < _reconnectAttempts) || (_reconnectAttempts == -1))
                        Thread.Sleep(_reconnectInterval);
                    try
                    {
                        _innerConnection.Close();
                        try
                        {
                            _innerConnection.Open();
                        }
                        catch{}
                        //here ecception occurs. Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 
                        _innerConnection.Close(); // closing the corrupted connection
                        _innerConnection.Open(); // opening the new connection
                            //tut vnezapno poyavlaetsya transport connection, kuda mojno pisat' dannie
                        _pingCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        restored = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception){}
                    retries--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But recently I have developed an app with Entity Framework and similar exception occurs here also. I can't develop previous workaround for Entity Framework.

1. Does anyone encounter such problem with MySql ?
2. What is the actual reason behind this exception?

[Where the error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N5ZT.jpg)

[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRGxL.jpg)

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this @Nurlan? I am getting it while using MVC5, EF6 and MySQL 5.6

Comment: For me reason is that I was using an opened connection through lifetime of DbContext and after some time connection was going to inactive state and therefore I was getting this exception

Answer (score 1):

The connection will expire and terminated by the host after some time. This is managed by MySql so nothing you can do in the code.

If particular query takes a long time to execute (some of my queries takes ~ 20 mins to return), you can set the timeout via the connection string - just add this to you connection string `"ConnectionIdleTimeout=1800;Command Timeout=0;"`.

The Connection idle time out stops the mySql server from killing the connection until the given time (it's not recommended to set it to 0, otherwise eventually the host will be swamped with the open connections, and report an error or max open connections exceeding the limit), while the command timeout = 0 stops any command to timeout by itself. A combination of the two should help with the error.

However, I don't personally like to cache the DbConnection, given the timeout behavior from the server side. I prefer to rely solely on the server to time out the connections, and on C# side, I usually just use:

`using MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("yourConnectionString"); connection.Open();`